# restore from emulation on google chrome

Tags: emulation, google-chrome-devtools, reset

I wanted to check how one of my local HTML page looks in different device. So, I launched the page in chrome and enabled in emulator. After that I was unable to see the page in normal full size mode. I have reset the emulator, changed screen resolution, re launched the browser, reset settings, deleted user data, renamed the page, moved the page into a different folder... nothing seems working. But the browser is showing other sites properly. What am I missing? How to reset the emulator to normal view?